# Best way to use same object for adding records LINQ C#

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, reference

I am using an object of a database object class InvceDtl to add multiple records to the Invoice details table. What is the best way to reuse the same object?

```
InvDtl oInvDtl = new InvDtl(); // for inserting product

InvDtl.InvNo = invNo;
oInvDtl.ProdCode = ProdCode;
oInvDtl.ProdName = ProdName;
oInvDtl.Qty=qty;
oInvDtl.UnitPrce = UnitPrce;
oInvDtl.ExtPrce=ExtPrce;

dbContext.AddObject(oInvDtl);
dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
dbContext.Detach(oInvDtl);// --> should we detach oInvDtl object to use it again?

oInvDtl = new InvDtl(); // for inserting medication

oInvDtl.InvNo =invNo;
oInvDtl.MedCode =MedCode
.......
.......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reusing the *reference*, not the *object*. In an expression

```
oInvDtl = new InvDtl(); //Assignment #1
..... 
oInvDtl = new InvDtl(); //Assignment #2
```

after the first assignment (#1) the oInvDtl references (points to) one instance of InvDtl. After the second asignment (#2) the oInvDtl references another, unrelated instance of InvDtl. See [Wikipedia on References in computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29)